# Combining typescript generics and variable keys

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to combine generics and variable keys? I have a generic response body from an api... The response includes the same properties except for the actual data that will be dependent on the call.

```
interface GenericResponse<Type> {
   code: string;
   message: string;
   data: {
      page: 1;
      nextpage: 2;
      [key: string]: Type
   }
}
```

Then when using this interface, I want to be able to pass through the type...

```
this.http.get<GenericResponse<Client[]>>();
```

The key will never be the same and the type will neither, why I need it to be generic.

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide a [mre] with definitions for things like `Client` and some example values of your generic type?

Comment: Well you'd need to know the key(s), too. Does this solution do what you want? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIRNYCBKEDOADgPYj4QA8A0shAB6QgAm+y+YUoA5gDTIAqAPmQBvAFDJkCYkwgAuNh24BuCcgC2BfHC7zFnEF1WSmcMHDlrJI5IR16QAV3UAjaMuSYGd3Qqev3ZABfZAAyK1FkAG0AawgAT2RQZCoAXQV+YLEgsVyweMIUAGEAG2AMMGQAXlE1YCYFdgMuNRA4TUalQ2y8gpQAWXj+Puq0DCxcAhIySgByBDKK-Fm+UvLwKNTBXNkFuCgUaTJK9XiAeRcAKwVB4cKxU4vLgDpTc2efCDEAem-Jf4BAD0APwPc5XV5mODPBbrMD4H5-AFA0FiIA If so I can write it up an answer for you.

Comment: Or maybe just this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIRNYCBKEDOADgPYj4QA8AKgHzIDeAUMsgsQCYQBcy+YUoAOYBuZsgC2BfHEHde-IaJbs4YODyrIAZA2SEZckAFdxAI2jDkmAB5h9snsbMXkAX0bvGjMAE9CKAGEAG2AMMGQAXgYxYHYePgEQQTEQOEl4hSSPL19-ZABZHyo-FCj0TAFcAhIySnpWELD8HmDQ8ABtAF03Gi9OBCC4KBQ2MnDxHwB5UwArHkLi-0YJ6ZmAOhU1NfsIRgB6PZYj44A9AH5lqdmN1Tg1gbawfH3D49OLxiA